# How to write this as a recursive Haskell function?

Tags: haskell, recursion, syntax, sum

I'll illustrate what I want to do using Python (I want to write this in Haskell). I have this function:

```
def f(n):
    s=0
    for d in range(1,n+1):
        s+=d*(n//d)
    return(s)
```

Which is basically looping from d=1 to n inclusive, and summing up the values of d times the floor of n/d.

In want to do this in Haskell which I believe requires recursion. Python equivalent:

```
def f(d, n):
    if d == 0: return 0
    else: return d*(n//d) + f(d-1, n)
```

and then I'd call the function with `f(n, n)`.

What's the correct way to write this?

My attempt:

```
   f (d n) = if d == 0 then 0 else d * (n//d) + f (d - 1 n)
```

edit, full code:

```
main = do
    input_line <- getLine
    let n = read input_line :: Int
    f d n
        | d == 0 = 0
        | otherwise = d * (n `div` d) + f (d-1) n
    putStrLn f n n
    return ()
```

Comment: For reference, the idiomatic way to write this would be ```f n = sum $ (\d -> d * (n `quot` d)) <$> [1..n+1]```. I use `quot` instead of `div` because it is more efficient. `d` will never be negative, so it will behave the same. Also, `read <$> getLine` (aka first two lines of `main`) is better written `readLn`, and you do not need a `return ()`, because `putStrLn _ :: IO ()`.

Comment: Less expensively, `d*(n//d) == n - n % d`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you gave is nearly correct.

The correct way to write it is as follows:

```
f d n = if d == 0 then 0 else d * (n `div` d) + f (d-1) n
```

Integer division in haskell is done with the [div](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:div) keyword, whereas normal division is done with `/` as expected.

Secondly, in haskell you don't need to use brackets for function arguments, except where to ensure the correct precedence. In the above code, we need brackets for `(d-1)` to indicate it is one parameter, and n is the second parameter.

Finally, when writing pure code, it's generally a lot nicer to use guard syntax instead of if then else, like below:

```
f d n
    | d == 0 = 0
    | otherwise = d * (n `div` d) + f (d-1) n
```

If you do use if then else, it's generally a good idea to split into multiple lines, so it's a bit easier to read.

```
f d n = if d == 0
            then 0
            else d * (n `div` d) + f (d-1) n
```

And depending on the function, it might be a good idea to give the function name and parameters better names.

If you're calling this from a do block, there's a few ways to approach it.

```
f d n
    | d == 0 = 0
    | otherwise = d * (n `div` d) + f (d-1) n

main = do
    input_line <- getLine
    let n = read input_line :: Int
        output = f n n

    print output

    -- or convert to string manually

    putStrLn (show output)

    -- or call without binding to a variable

    -- $ is sort of like putting brackets around the f n n, so it is one
    -- parameter to print
    print $ f n n

    putStrLn . show $ f n n

    {- or we can bind the function to a let block - must be double indented
    let f d n
            | d == 0 = 0
            | otherwise = d * (n `div` d) + f (d - 1) n -}



    return ()

    {- you can also make functions in where blocks
    where f d n
        | d == 0 = 0
        | otherwise = d * (n `div` d) + f (d-1) n -}
```

Comment: For some reason it gives me a parse error on that first `|`

Comment: @user8926565 Have you indented it with a tab? Whitespace is significant in some places in haskell.

Comment: @user8926565 It's because you're in a do block, which is in the IO monad instead of in pure code. I updated my answer to show a few ways to use the function

Answer (score 0):

First, I wouldn't use a loop in the Python version, either:

```
def f(n):
    # s=0
    # for d in range(1,n+1):
    #     s+=d*(n//d)
    # return(s)
    return sum(d*(n//d) for d in range(1, n+1))
```

This is a natural approach in Haskell, as well.

```
f n = sum [d*(n `div` d) | d <- [1..n]]
```

However, this is inefficient, as you are performing a multiplication and a division for each element of the range. Instead, start by recognizing that

```
d * (n // d) == n - n % d  # Python
d * (n `div` d) == n - n `mod` d  # Haskell
```

which means you could write

```
sum(n - n % d for d in range(1, n+1)  # Python
sum [n - n `mod` d | d <- [1..n]]  # Haskell
```

You can take this a step further; the first `n` term doesn't depend on `d`, so you can pull that out of the sum and just multiply once:

```
n * n - sum(n % d for d in range(1, n+1))  # Python
n*n - sum [n `mod` d | d <- [1..n]]  # Haskell
```